# jQuery Change CSS value if class not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a lille script to go trough my page and check if a class is present in any `<div>`. If the class is present then there will be no action.

It will look for `class="blue"` and if it find it it will do nothing. If it doesn't fint `class="blue"` it will change background color for `class="yellow"`. What it does it change the background color for `class="yellow"` not matter what. What is wrong?

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).attr('class') != undefined && jQuery(this).hasClass('blue')) {} else {
    $('.yellow').css('background', 'green')
  }
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
  Blue
</div>

<div class="red">
  Red
</div>

<div class="yellow">
  Yellow
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this one. Hold on...

Comment: `$('.yellow').css('background', 'green');` would get the same result.

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured it out... Please wait...

Comment: `jQuery(this).attr('class') != undefined` <-- why are you doing this?

Comment: Your code is saying, hey the first div has the class blue.... next one.... hey the class is not blue....

Comment: @epascarello I'm trying to create a loop. Yet this class will only be present one time only. This script was my best guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner... :)

http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/bcgajp6q/

Basically, you want that if a blue is there, the `.yellow` is green. Otherwise, it stays yellow.

You can see what happens when the blue is there by going to the fiddle (^above) and uncommenting the blue.

```js
if(!$(".blue").length) $(".yellow").css('background-color', 'green');
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <div class="blue">
  Blue
</div> -->
<div class="red">
  Red
</div>

<div class="yellow">
  Yellow
</div>
```

Comment: I just need it the other way around but I like your approach. This finds the `blue` and returns green. I need it to check that `blue` doesn't exist and then change the value on the other css-class.

Comment: So if blue doesn't exist, then change the `.yellow`? Ok

Comment: I've got it! Thanks a lot! The `!` was the missing part! I will approach with your script :)

Comment: You mean: "Basically, you want that if blue is NOT there, the .yellow is green."

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply check if the target element doesn't have the `.blue` class (with `if (!$(this).hasClass('blue'))`).

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('blue')) {
    $('.yellow').css('background', 'green')
  }
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
  Blue
</div>

<div class="red">
  Red
</div>

<div class="yellow">
  Yellow
</div>
```

Comment: This does exactly what my own script does :(